# Event ID: 10027 Source: MSExchangeIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, vmware-esxi

I get his **Event ID: 10027 Source: MSExchangeIS** error:

> There are 5 RPC requests for the mailbox
>   "47b20bd7-28e0-423f-b458-234639311bd6: /o=DOMAIN/ou=First
>   Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=NGoodman" on the database
>   "17f2215b-b8b1-4d26-b7a3-392130962eb7: /o=DOMAIN/ou=Exchange
>   Administrative Group
>   (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=XXX-XXXXXXX-XX/cn=Microsoft
>   Private MDB" that have taken an abnormally long time to complete. This
>   may be indicative of performance issues with your server.

I can't seem to find any on the Event ID.  Can anyone point me to the right direction?  Or at least point me into the right direction, please.

I am running Exchange 2010 on Windows 2008 R2 enterprise in ESXi 5.0 VMWare environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RPC` = "Remote Procedure Call"

It's nothing you need to worry about, unless you see a lot of it, and/or are having performance issues on your Exchange server.  It basically just means that something (5 somethings) are taking longer than Windows thinks it should to perform an operation remotely on that mailbox.  Could be a search, could be mailbox maintenance operations, could be some stupid user trying email a BluRay movie, and so on.

[There's a blog post about it on technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/03/21/information-store-timeout-detection-in-exchange-2007-sp3.aspx), some of which is quoted below.

> In isolation, an individual long running transaction may or may not be of concern. If the transaction doesn’t involve any locking, it will proceed in isolation without harm (assuming CPU and Memory are scaled appropriately). If it does use locking however, it can be quite harmful to the experience of other clients as they wait for the locked resource to be released.
>
> If the prevalence of long transactions increases over time, the monitoring more than likely indicates that there are various problems (data corruption, high item counts, disk performance, memory pressure, CPU pressure).

Comment: It doesn't happen often, but maybe once every few days to once a day or so.  I also should have mentioned that we are in the process of making a DR site, so that could cause some issues too.

Comment: @George still probably won't cause issues, no, but could be caused by setting up a DR site, depending on how you're doing it.  Like it says, it's just an informational alert that something's taking a long time on the mailbox in question, which could be completely normal.